# Is there a way to get Google Forms FormResponse responses broken down by Section in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps, google-forms

I'm working with a Google Form and an Apps Script project tied to it. The function I'm calling on submit takes the form responses and works with them to make a new Doc. The number of questions that the submitter has answered, however, can change depending on what sections the form brought them to or had them skip over.

I'm working with a FormsResponse object onSubmit. I'm able to get the question names and responses, but not the sections.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getItemResponses()

Is there some way to break these responses down and group them by sections? Something like `FormsResponse.getItemResponsesBySection()` or something?

Comment: You could "hard code" an object that associates the question ID with a section grouping.  So, you would be defining what questions go with what groups inside of the object.  To get the data out, the code needs to match the question (Item) ID in the object with the question ID in the response data.  `{"sectionOne":["12345","54321"],"sectionTwo":["98765","73538"]}`   In that object, there is a section name associated with an array of item IDs of the questions in that section.  So, again, you are defining what question (item) is associated with what section name.

Comment: The problem with "simply hard-coding" it is, the number of responses that I get `onSubmit()` can vary depending on what sections the respondent visited. You're right that the object you described is what I'm after, but how do I arrive there when I don't know what section answer #52 actually is from?